# Are "switched" TRS connector pins (sense pins) suitable for audio multiplexing?

Tags: audio, connector, datasheet, multiplexer

TRS jacks are commonly available with "switched" or "sense" contacts, like this:

[image]

This form is commonly used to ground the input pins when nothing is plugged in. But can these contacts also be used to multiplex an audio signal, like this?

[image]

The idea is to use an external signal when a plug is in, but a separate fallback signal when unplugged. For this to work, it seems like the following characteristics would be important:

- Low and well-defined sense contact resistance (from pin 2 to 3 and from pin 4 to 5). I.e., minimize distortion of the fallback signal.
- Extremely high resistance and low parasitic capacitance between sense and "real" contacts when plugged in. I.e., minimize crosstalk between the signal from the plug and the "fallback" signal.

I've looked at a number of datasheets ([CUI SJ1-352XN](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/670/sj1_352xn-1779157.pdf), [Amphenol ACJM-NV35-2](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/18/55010544000110_acjx-nv35-x-771264.pdf), [Kobiconn 16PJ108-EX](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/253/KC-300848-1177590.pdf), [Kycon STX-3120-5B](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/222/STX3120-334667.pdf)) and haven't found any clear statements about these properties. Some of them list "contact resistance," but it's not clearly stated whether this value also applies to the sense contacts. Others don't mention contact resistance at all, and none of them mention any crosstalk properties.

I do have two kinds of these jacks (the Kycon STX-3120-5B and an unidentifiable generic, i.e. cheap garbage) and have tried to measure these properties myself. Sense contact resistance for both measures in the tens of milli-ohms unplugged and "off-scale high" for my meter when plugged in. So it seems promising, but I don't know if I can *rely* on these characteristics after a healthy number of mating cycles and in all connectors in a batch.

Is this a normal, sane thing to do or are these pins really not meant for this purpose?

The input signal in my application is rated up to +4 dBu (about 3.5 Vpp) and the connector feeds an audio preamplifier with a ~20k input impedance (current through the connector is thus a fraction of a mA).

Comment: You can rely on the characteristics much better if you ensure you use high quality jacks.   You're looking at 3.5MM TRS  ...  IME  Those are extremely fragile and flaky.    $$$$  Keep in mind also, because it's not obvious, as you insert or remove the plug, multiple pins may momentarily short-circuit together.   You'll also get people half-plugging the jack (i.e. only so far as the ring, not reaching the tip)

Comment: @KyleB Yes, you get what you pay for: this was a case of me not knowing whether I was paying for these particular sense contact characteristics (as an analogy, you can't rely on even an expensive luxury car to be bulletproof, because that's not a design goal of most cars). Your point is well taken though. Regarding make-before-break, I've considered that... the design is already current-limited and should be safe against this or short-circuiting at the connector.

Comment: Might add.... IMO what you'll likely get with "high quality jacks" is mostly better plating.  These are spring-steel contacts, ideally with a nickel plating for hardness, corrosion resistance etc.   The thickness (or even presence) of that plating is "more likely to be better" with higher quality stuff.  There's also potentially mechanical advantage.. A company with experience would attempt to design the contacts such that there is some amount of 'wiping' action instead of just a single point of contact.  So many details, you'd never know until you make 50,000 units and start getting returns.

Comment: The 3.5mm jack is likely to be the weakest point of your whole system.   I don't know your budget but man, if you're gonna 'overbuild' any part of it, it should be that jack. $$$$  IMO and all that of course  ;)    I speak from the position of a guy who fixes alotta audio gear... Those 3.5mm jacks are universally trouble prone. $$$$  BTW -- Maybe you already thought of it but worth saying ... Use a THROUGH HOLE type device, not SMT if at all possible.  MUCH more mechanically stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard technique in audio consoles, called "jack normalling".

There are many ways it can be configured: as in your case to insert an external input in place of the normal internal one, in a left/mono, right/stereo scheme where unplugging from right jack cause right signal to route to left's ring, or as an effects return where your signal is output on the ring and returns, effected, on the tip.

As to your other concerns, contact resistance and parasitic capacitance - these are completely insignificant at these levels and frequencies.

Any decent quality jack should work fine - professional companies ship zillions of units with this scheme.